# json request causes the browser to display a popup, I set JsonResult in the action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

My code:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DoBlah()
{
    ..

    return Json(mySerializedObject);
}
```

In firebug, **I can see the response content type is using application/json.**

But for some reason, I get a popup with the json response.

What could the issue be here?

Comment: Are you issuing a regular POST instead of an Ajax one? Check that out. Ajax call would never open a new browser window (if that's what you mean by *popup*).

Comment: Can you provide the code that calls the Json method?

Comment: He could be having the same problem as this guy:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357901/net-mvc-json-response-opens-up-dialog-box-to-save

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your browser doesn't know how to handle application/json.

If you were using a one of the jQuery Ajax functions like  [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to retrieve the data  you shouldn't experience this problem.

It's hard to say exactly because we don't know the method your using to request that data.